# Same member function of a class can be declared with "override & final" specifier in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

[override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) and [final](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) specifier has been introduced in C++11.The below program uses these specifier as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
void display(const T& val) { std::cout<<val<<"\n"; }

class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape()= default;
    virtual void Draw() { display("Shape::Draw()");}
   virtual void DisplayName() { display("Shape");}
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Circle() = default;
    virtual void Draw() override final { display("Circle::Draw()");}
    virtual void DisplayName() override { display("Cicle");}
};


int main()
{
}
```

In the above sample program `Circle::Draw()` has been defined as `override final` specifier. This compiles successfully however if the same method is defined as `final override`, then it throws an **compile time** error.

Wanted to understand the use cases of override and final specifier for the same method for a class?. When we should use it in our program?

Comment: My compiler (GCC 4.7) doesn't object to `final override.`  What compiler are you using?

Comment: And you expect us to comment on a compile time error we don't even know? Post the error please.

Comment: Cannot able to reproduce with GCC, 4.8.2 Clang 3.4 and MSVC++2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is a compiler bug. At least at www.ideone com the code is compiled successfully.

Acoording to the C++ Standard (10.3 Virtual functions)

> 4 If a virtual function f in some class B is marked with the
>   virt-specifier final and in a **class D derived from B** a function
>   D::f overrides B::f, the program is ill-formed.

```
[ Example: 
struct B {
virtual void f() const final;
};
struct D : B {
void f() const; // error: D::f attempts to override final B::f
};
—end example ]
```

A class may not be a derived class of itself. So the code you showed shall be compiled.

Also

> 5 If a virtual function is marked with the virt-specifier override and
>   does not override a member function of a base class, the program is
>   ill-formed.

```
[ Example:
struct B {
virtual void f(int);
};
struct D : B {
virtual void f(long) override; // error: wrong signature overriding B::f
virtual void f(int) override; // OK
};
—end example ]
```

In your example function Draw of class Circle is marked with virt-specidier override and indeed overrides the function of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compiler bug. According to the grammar that the C++11 standard is specifying in [class.mem]:

> *member-declarator:
>          declarator
>   virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>
>
>           declarator
>   brace-or-equal-initializer<sub>opt</sub>
>
>           identifier<sub>opt</sub>
>   attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> : constant-expression
>
>   virt-specifier-seq:
>
>           virt-specifier
>
>           virt-specifier-seq
>   virt-specifier
>  virt-specifier:*
>           `override`
>           `final`

The *virt-specifier-seq* doesn't imply any order in the *virt-specifier*s in the declaration.

> When we should use it in our program?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730375/explicit-overrides-and-final-c0x) might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Vlad from Moscow is correct

[From the override specifier at cppreference.com:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

> > declarator virt-specifier-seq(optional) function-body
> >     In both cases, virt-specifier-seq, if used, is either override or final, or **final override** or **override final**.

[And again for the final specifier at cppreference.com:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

> > declarator virt-specifier-seq(optional) function-body
> >     virt-specifier-seq, if used, is either override or final, or **final override** or **override final**.

Compiler bugs aside, I would encourage you to pick an order and stick to it consistently - don't mix and match the word order through your codebase.